# Checking if geometry in one table exists in another using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I am trying to find the number of animals each state has. I first did this query:

```
    COUNT(*)  from animals c, locations a where st_contains(a.geom,c.the_geom);
```

But for some reason I get a syntax error. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Below are examples of my two tables.

Animals table

```
      animal_type     city area     the_geom
       9            243582        82F4100000000F0BB0D41

       4           11234         6C892E410000000040170

       3           243582        82F4100000000F0BB0D41

      12          11234         6C892E410000000040170
```

Location table

```
     State        gid                  geom

     WV           3                    82F4100000000F0BB0D41

     TX             2                    6C892E410000000040170
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "select" keyword before count(*):

```
select COUNT(*) from animals c, locations a where ST_Contains(a.geom,c.the_geom);
```

This returns count of all animals inside all locations (single number). If you need to count animals for each location, you have to use group by syntax:

```
select a.state, COUNT(*) from animals c, locations a where ST_Contains(a.geom,c.the_geom) group by state;
```